# Using lookup structure to search pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to PySpark and I'm trying to create a generic .where() function, that can accept any lookup structure and use that to check if the value is present

```py
TYPES = ('TYPE_1', 'TYPE_2', 'TYPE_3')
```

Something like this:

```py
(
  df.where(
     df.value in TYPES
  )
)
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can construct an array column from your lookup structure and use `array_contains` to filter whether the column contains an element in your structure.

e.g.

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,),(2,),(3,)],['column'])
>>> arr = [2,3,4]
>>> df.withColumn('contains', F.array_contains(F.array(*[F.lit(i) for i in arr]), F.col('column'))).show()
+------+--------+
|column|contains|
+------+--------+
|     1|   false|
|     2|    true|
|     3|    true|
+------+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you for this, are you aware of any other ways of doing this?

Comment: @Bob another way could be to use a UDF, but it will be slower than this method which utilised native Spark SQL functions

Comment: yes I have been reading about UDFs. Ok that's good to know - in your answer, rather than returning the true/false table, how would you just return the `columns` that is true.

Comment: Just add a filter at the end: `df.withColumn('contains', F.array_contains(F.array(*[F.lit(i) for i in arr]), F.col('column'))).filter('contains = 1')`

Comment: Is this also possible with dict? or tuples?

Comment: Spark columns cannot be Python dicts or Python tuples.

Comment: `.where(F.col(col_name).isin(list))` ?